# SalesforceNetwork Plugin has an issue on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm using Ionic as an app and portal for the frontend, and the backend is Salesforce, for which we use the Salesforce SDK. Right now, I have an issue that only happens on Android. When requesting an API call, it gets a request timeout of 20 seconds. It was consistent when I tried to request again.

Here is the code for the service class

```
  public CreateMTRCase(param): Promise<any> {
    const service = DataService.getInstance();
    if (!service) {
      return;
    }
    param.id = service.getUserId();
    return service.request({
      path: '/services/apexrest/Example',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      method: 'POST',
      data: param,
      useProxy: false,
    });
  }
```

Here is the class that is submitting the data or requesting the data:

```
async submitRequest(modalCss: string) {
    this.modal = modalCss;
    this.isLoading = true;
    const objparam = this.prepareMTRCase();
    console.log("Object params: "+JSON.stringify(objparam));
    const service = this.medTransSvc.CreateMTRCase(objparam);
    service
      .then(
        (response) => {
          if (response.error) {
            let errorMessage: string = response.error;
            if (errorMessage.includes(CommonConstants.NOT_ELIGIBLE)) {
              this.abandonMTR(CommonConstants.NOT_ELIGIBLE);
            }
            return;
          }
          if (response.success === false && response.recordId === null) {
            this.isSuccess = false;
            return;
          }
          if (response.recordId !== null) {
            this.recordId = response.recordId;
            // getToken
            this.getToken(this.filesToUpload, this.recordId);
          }
          
        },
        (err) => {
            const str = JSON.stringify(err);
            console.log("Error: "+str);
            this.abandonMTR('process');
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        this.abandonMTR('process');
      });
  }
```

When requesting the API call, it falls to the "err" function, resulting in a gateway timeout. It always happens on Android, but on iOS and Portal, it works perfectly.

The error shows that in 20 seconds it will throw an error: the request is being failed, and the error message is timeout.

[image: pgSendRequest]

Do you have any idea why is error happens only on Android

Here is my ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.3 (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.4.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 28 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v10.24.1 (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.14.12
   OS      : macOS
   Xcode   : Xcode 14.2 Build version 14C18
```

The dependencies which I installed on ionic

```
{
  "name": "MyCare",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/analytics-firebase": "^5.44.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.39.1",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/preview-any-file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.38",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "forcejs": "file:lib/forcejs",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "idlejs": "^3.0.0",
    "ionic-pullup": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.4",
    "ngx-lottie": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@havesource/cordova-plugin-push": "^1.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin": "git+https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin.git#v8.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-androidx-build": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-annotated-plugin-android": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-play-services-version-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-analytics": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "^1.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.9.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-preview-any-file": "^0.2.9",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.4.1",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.20",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "com.salesforce": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "mycare",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "dev4-top-internationalsos.cs32.force.com",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "havesource-cordova-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "186917679445"
      },
      "cordova-support-google-services": {},
      "@havesource/cordova-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "186917679445"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-androidx-build": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "17.0.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location while this app runs only.",
        "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-analytics": {},
      "cordova-plugin-preview-any-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```